# Print Header Band in Summary Band in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've a report that has a header band, detail band, and summary band. I'm trying to push the summary band always to be on a new page using the report property "Summary on a new page", I want to display the header band along with the summary band. How can I achieve that?

I'm using Jasper Reports 3.7.6 and iReports 1.2

Comment: It seems that you're saying, "The summary must be on a new page" and saying "The summary must not be on a new page" since you want it on the same page with one of the group headers. Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to print the summary along with the header in one page, right now I can print the summary in one page but I can't figure how to print the header with summary

Comment: So please update the question to reflect your current question. For example, mention that you don't want the summary on a new page, and clarify what band "the header" refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want the summary to begin on a new page, but that page should still have the page header that appears on all the other pages.

In the past this could be solved by unchecking the new page option and instead starting your summary band with a `break` element, but Jaspersoft has since added a `"Summary with Page Header and Footer"` option to solve this precise problem.

iReport 1.2 may not give you that option, in which case you should move to iReport 3.7.6. (Not the latest version! The iReport version you use should always match the version of Jasper Reports you want to compile with.)

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions, before 3.7.6, you can put your content on band.

> 'lastPageFooterBand',

because the header content gonna be repeated. In my case, I was using ireport 3.0, worked perfectly.

Or you can create your own band:

> 'yourOwnHeaderBand'
>   or 
>   'yourOwnFooterBand'